# Timer running in background in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, service, notifications

I'm try to handling timer running in background and show this timer in drawer notification
So i was try using flutter-background-service
But this package throw exception from flutter-background-service-android
Is there any to make the timer works
For Android and ios

I'm try flutter-background-service
And i expect to work in background and for notification

Comment: your question is very vague with no clear details of the exceptions you are getting , this won't get you an answer, I recommend adding more details

Comment: You should at least provide [a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)